# Assert and SoftAssert errors in a @Test

Tags: java

```
public class TEST extends BaseSetup{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        try {
            softAssert.assertEquals(1, 6);
            Assert.assertEquals(2,5);
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            softAssert.assertAll();
        }
    }
}
```

(ItestResult result) shows only softAssert exception but i need Assert exception also.

Answer (score 0):

**finally** block has the highest priority. An exception from finally block supersedes an exception from try block. It can not failed on Assert and softAssert together. You should add simple assert to softAssert either handle Assert and softAssert failures separately